# Stop windows service using batch file with c#

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file, windows-services

I have a windows service which I need to turn it off using code written in a batch file, I tried many codes but none of them worked with me, the solution stuck in a point and do not continue running. This is my code in c#

```
 Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe";
if (File.Exists(p.StartInfo.FileName))
{
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "Stop_Service.bat";
p.Start();

p.WaitForExit()

}
```

and this is the code written inside the batch file:

```
net stop myService
```

Comment: So your question is how to run a batch file? What the batch file does is not relevant to the C# code. Where exactly is this batch file located? Why not simply pass that path directly to `Process.Start`?

Comment: There is no need at all to use a batch file. You could use net.exe or even the significantly better sc.exe directly, and I'm sure that you could perform your task directly in C# without using either of those two utilities too.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Windows servicies, in this case you can use the `Systems.ServiceProcess` namespace which gives API to control Windows servicies

```
using System.ServiceProcess;

ServiceController serviceController = new ServiceController("myService");
serviceController.Stop();
```

The code is very simple. This API is available also for .NET Core as a NuGet package